# Generating PMML export of a gbm model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting, pmml

Is it possible to generate PMML of a gbm model?  When I try to use the pmml library, I get an error:

> Error in UseMethod("pmml") :
>      no applicable method for 'pmml' applied to an object of class "gbm"

Ideally, I'd like to export into PMML but I could live with another format I can parse programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PMML makes sense if you want to deploy your model directly to a PMML scoring engine such as [JPMML](https://github.com/jpmml).

Otherwise, use generic serialization mechanisms. R lets you store and load data structures using built-in functions `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`, respectively. Please note that the RDS data format is specific to R and it will be difficult to work with in other languages/environments.

For cross-platform support you might check out Google's ProtoBuf serialization mechanism as implemented in the [RProtoBuf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RProtoBuf/) package. I have used this library for the export of R's Random Forest models:

```
library("RProtoBuf")
rf = randomForest(target ~ ., data = mydata)
con = file("rf.pb", open = "wb")
serialize_pb(rf, con)
close(con)
```

Comment: Thanks!  In the end, I ended up writing a custom export and then implementing a scorer on Scala -- but I didn't find a better answer than this one, and maybe I should have just gone with this approach.

Comment: I used this approach to build a PMML exporter for Random Forest models (my Java implementation is approximately 100x faster than R implementation). The internals of the `gbm` model data structure are very similar to `randomForest` model data structure, so it would be straightforward to build a PMML exporter for GBM models as well.

Comment: @user1808924 have you made any information about your exporter public, eg a Github repo? I'd be very interested in taking a look

Comment: @Moderat You should check out https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-r (Java library and command line app) and https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml (its R wrapper). The ProtoBuf data format isn't so easy to work with, though. Have switched from ProtoBuf to RDS by now.